# XML response parsing with Spring RestTemplate on Android

Tags: java, android, spring, web-services, rest

My goal is to parse the response  I get back from my REST service api.
My problem is that in case of Date fields the parser throws

`org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read [class com.example.sfeher.myapplication.HrpEventsHelper]; nested exception is java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2015-09-15T00:00:00+02:00" (at offset 10)`

---

My service interface:

```
@Path("/")

@WebService(name="HrpRESTService", targetNamespace="http://ws.xxx.hu/rest")
@Secured("ROLE_WS")

public interface HrpRESTService {



@Path("/get")    
@POST
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})  
public Response showMe();
}

My rest service method from my implementing class:

@Override
public Response showMe() {
    customBo.getDaoSession().beginTransaction();
    List l=customBo.findAll(HrpEvents.class);
    customBo.getDaoSession().getTransaction().commit();
    //GenericEntity> ge=new GenericEntity>(l){};
    HrpEventsHelper helper=new HrpEventsHelper();
    helper.setTitle(l.get(0).getTitle());
    helper.setUrgency(l.get(0).getUrgency());
    helper.setEventDate(l.get(0).getEventDate());
    return Response.ok(helper).build();
 }
```

I use Android Studio with following dependencies:

```
    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.6.2'
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE'
    compile 'com.hannesdorfmann:httpkit-simple-xml:1.5.5'
   }
```

And finally the relevant part of my client code:

```
        headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML));
        map = new LinkedMultiValueMap();
        map.add("access_token", tokenMap.get("access_token"));

        request = new HttpEntity>(map, headers);

        messageConverters = new ArrayList>();
        messageConverters.add(new SimpleXmlHttpMessageConverter());
        messageConverters.add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
        restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

        HrpEventsHelper response=restTemplate.postForObject(apiURL, request, HrpEventsHelper.class);

        System.out.println(response.getTitle());
```

My entity helper class:

```
package com.example.sfeher.myapplication;

    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.Date;

public class HrpEventsHelper implements Serializable {

private String title;
private String urgency;
Date eventDate;

public HrpEventsHelper() {
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getUrgency() {
    return urgency;
}

public void setUrgency(String urgency) {
    this.urgency = urgency;
}

public Date getEventDate() {
    return eventDate;
}

public void setEventDate(Date eventDate) {
    this.eventDate = eventDate;
}
}
```